# Using \acs* within \ch (acro + chemformula)

Tags: chemmacros, acro, chemformula

When calling an acronym, it might a) have been used somewhere in the document before or b) be used for the first time. In case b, one would require the acro package to print the long form. Sometimes, the printing of the long form should be delayed. A good way to achieve this is `\acs*{}`, which will print the short version and not 'use' the acronym. Using `\acifused{}{}{}`, one can then control the output in an if-else-fashion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\DeclareAcronym{bdc}{short=bdc,long=\iupac{benzene-1,4-dicarboxylate}}

\begin{document}
I don't want the \acs*{bdc} acronym be printed in its long form here; Instead, I'll put the explanation within parentheses in case the acronym was called for the first time\acifused{bdc}{}{ (\acs{bdc}: \acl{bdc})}.
\end{document}
```

[image: result of MWE using \acs*{}]

However, trying to adapt this to the `\ch{}` command like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\DeclareAcronym{bdc}{short=bdc,long=\iupac{benzene-1,4-dicarboxylate}}

\begin{document}
The compound of interest is \ch{[Zn4O(\acs*{bdc})3]}\acifused{bdc}{}{ (\acs{bdc}: \acl{bdc})}.
\end{document}
```

will lead to pdflatex ending in error:

```
! Package acro Error: You've requested acronym `\chemformula_star_adduct: ' on
(acro)                line 13 but you apparently haven't defined it, yet!
(acro)                Maybe you've misspelled `\chemformula_star_adduct: '?

Type <return> to continue.
```

I made sure that `\ac{}` is working inside the `\ch{}` command and `\acs*{}` is working outside of `\ch{}`. However, `\acs*{}` is not working inside `\ch{}` for me. I'm using an up-to-date version of TeX Live 2019. What are your ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message gives a hint: the main problem with the input `\ch{[Zn4O(\acs*{bdc})3]}` is the star `*`. `chemformula` interprets it as a adduct, see the corresponding section of `chemformula's` manual.

The way out is the same as in most of the cases when you want to put something unusual or “weird” into `\ch`: use the escape mechanism `"..."`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\DeclareAcronym{bdc}{short=bdc,long=\iupac{benzene-1,4-dicarboxylate}}

\begin{document}

The compound of interest is \ch{[Zn4O( "\acs*{bdc}" )3]}
\acifused{bdc}{}{ (\acs{bdc}: \acl{bdc})}.

\end{document}
```

[image]